# created directory not show in user page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to show created directory in ASP.NET? When user creating directory to his account how to show created directory to user web page. User create their own directory when user required.

```
try
{
    if (tvFolders.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode();
        fileNode.Text = tvFolders.SelectedValue.ToString();
        //string rootPath = tvFolders.SelectedNode.Text;
        string rootPath = fileNode.Text;

        Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath + "/" + txtDirName.Text);
        lblMessage.Text = "Directory created";
    }
    else
        lblMessage.Text = "Directory already exists";
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, notify the user that the directory has been created? Kind of a popup? The lblMessage.Text will not display the value as requested here because nothing is sent back to the client. If you want a popup you can consider using a bit of JavaScript to show a popup, or change the lblMessage through JavaScript.

Comment: no sir not popup. the problem is user created directory /folder show to user his account page(web page). just like docmonster.uk.co

Answer (score 0):

I think you'er gonna have to use the "Server.MapPath" with your rootPath too. Web applications are different that desktops, so the "Current Directory" works differently in them.

```
String Root = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Your Path"
```